# How can I add and read replies of a discussion thread using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, discussion-board

How can I reply to a discussion.

This is my add discussion code but not for reply.

```
$("#submitReply").click(function (){
    var newElement = new Object();
    newElement.Body = document.getElementById('reply_message').value;
    var activmeta = { Title: newElement.title, Body: newElement.Body }
    addListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, 'LFeed', activmeta,alert, '')
    return false;
});
```

to add reply, I tried to add the `parentItemId`, but it dosent work.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

I copied below code from blog http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/01/20/working-with-discussions-list-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/

**Create Discussion**

```
function createDiscussion(listTitle,properties,OnItemAdded,OnItemError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    context.load(list);

    var discussionItem = SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussion(context, list, properties.Subject);
    for(var propName in properties) {
       if(propName == 'Subject') continue; 
       discussionItem.set_item(propName, properties[propName]) 
    }
    discussionItem.update();
    context.load(discussionItem);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(discussionItem);           
        },
        OnItemError
    );
}
```

**Creating messages**

```
function createMessage(discussionItem,properties,OnItemAdded,OnItemError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var messageItem = SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply(context, discussionItem);
    for(var propName in properties) {
       messageItem.set_item(propName, properties[propName]) 
    }
    messageItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(messageItem);           
        },
        OnItemError
    );
}

function createMessages(discussionItem,messagesProperties,OnItemsAdded,OnItemsError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var messageItems = [];
    $.each(messagesProperties, function (i, properties) {
       messageItems.push(SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply(context, discussionItem));
       for(var propName in properties) {
          messageItems[i].set_item(propName, properties[propName]) 
       }
       messageItems[i].update();       
    });

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemsAdded(messageItems);           
        },
        OnItemsError
    );
}
```

Comment: OP wants to add discussions/replies using REST API and not JSOM

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to create a message (reply) in Discussion Board via SharePoint REST API.

**Example**

```
var listTitle = "Discussions"; //Discussions Board title
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var messagePayload = {
   '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },  //set DiscussionBoard entity type name
   'Body': "Thanks for the information",  //message Body
   'FileSystemObjectType': 0, //set to 0 to make sure Message Item is created
   'ContentTypeId': '0x0107008822E9328717EB48B3B665EE2266388E', //set Message content type
   'ParentItemID': 14  //set Discussion item (topic) Id
};

createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('Message(reply) has been sent');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,payload){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": payload
    });
}

function moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,folderUrl){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")?$select=FileDirRef,FileRef";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url
    })  
    .then(function(result){
        var fileUrl = result.d.FileRef;
        var fileDirRef = result.d.FileDirRef;
        var moveFileUrl = fileUrl.replace(fileDirRef,folderUrl);
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + moveFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
        return executeJson({
            "url" :url,
            "method": 'POST'
        });
     });
}


function getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,itemId){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")/Folder";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
    });
}


function createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle, messagePayload){ 
    var topicUrl = null;
    return getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload.ParentItemID)
    .then(function(result){
        topicUrl = result.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
        return createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        var itemId = result.d.Id;
        return moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,topicUrl);
    });
}
```

**The explanation**

- since a Discussion Board contains discussions and messages, the following properties needs to be specified for a message payload: `FileSystemObjectType=0`, `ContentTypeId`- content type Id of message item, `ParentItemID` - discussion item id
- for setting parent discussion  item, `ParentItemID` property of Message content type is used, but it **cant** be specified via payload since it is a *read only* property (the next item explains how message is created under a discussion)
- since a discussion item (topic) is represented as a *folder* in
  Discussion Board list, this is what the method `moveListItem` is intended for, once message item is created, it getting moved under a discussion item

Comment: While this appears to work (the reply shows up in the discussion thread of the parent post) it does not set the `ParentItemID` property on the reply, it remains `null` which breaks some of the features of discussions. See this article: [REST api support for discussion list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d4de96cc-53eb-4579-a7d4-97e575b08620/rest-api-support-for-new-discussion-list-in-community-site-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)