# Adding Discussion board replies using REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, discussion-board

Can anybody please help me by providing some sample code for adding replies to Discussion lists using REST API? I already have a look on [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122139/how-can-i-add-and-read-replies-of-a-discussion-thread-using-rest-api), but the answered guy has given the jsom solution. But i need a REST API solution. Please help. It's something urgent for us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `SP.Utilities` namespace may not be exposed via REST.  Is there a reason you cannot use JSOM?

Comment: Hi, the front end will be the Android platform. So weed the REST API

Comment: @MAC hello. have you get Solution for this.??

Answer (score 2):

Even though [`SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408981(v=office.14).aspx) is not exposed via SharePoint REST API, the following example demonstrates how to create a message (or reply) to a discussion item:

**Example**

```
var listTitle = "Discussions"; //Discussions Board title
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var messagePayload = {
   '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },  //set DiscussionBoard entity type name
   'Body': "Thanks for the information",  //message Body
   'FileSystemObjectType': 0, //setto 0 to make sure Mesage Item
   'ContentTypeId': '0x0107008822E9328717EB48B3B665EE2266388E', //set Message content type
   'ParentItemID': 14  //set Discussion item (topic) Id
};





createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('Message(reply) has been sent');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("data" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,payload){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": payload
    });
}

function moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,folderUrl){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")?$select=FileDirRef,FileRef";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url
    })  
    .then(function(result){
        var fileUrl = result.d.FileRef;
        var fileDirRef = result.d.FileDirRef;
        var moveFileUrl = fileUrl.replace(fileDirRef,folderUrl);
        var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + moveFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
        return executeJson({
            "url" :url,
            "method": 'POST'
        });
     });
}


function getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,itemId){
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getItemById(" + itemId + ")/Folder";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
    });
}


function createNewDiscussionReply(webUrl,listTitle, messagePayload){ 
    var topicUrl = null;
    return getParentTopic(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload.ParentItemID)
    .then(function(result){
        topicUrl = result.d.ServerRelativeUrl;
        return createListItem(webUrl,listTitle,messagePayload);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        var itemId = result.d.Id;
        return moveListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,topicUrl);
    });
}
```

[`createNewDiscussionReply.js` gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/c5327ddbb1ceede884c14e35bb21117e)

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. But really? It requires 5 network calls to create a discussion reply?

Comment: I'm afraid so. The point is that ParentItemId property is not settable and in order to create a reply the item (which represents a message) is getting moved under a folder (which represents a subject) once it is created

Comment: While this appears to work (the reply shows up in the discussion thread of the parent post) it does not set the `ParentItemID` property on the reply, it remains `null` which breaks some of the features of discussions. See this article for why: [REST api support for discussion list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d4de96cc-53eb-4579-a7d4-97e575b08620/rest-api-support-for-new-discussion-list-in-community-site-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)