# REST API to add replies to a share point discussion

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, discussion-board, api

I am able to post a reply to share point discussion with help of below link.

[REST Call to Post a Reply to a Discussion Board Topic w/o JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152957/rest-call-to-post-a-reply-to-a-discussion-board-topic-w-o-jsom)

but here for posting a message ContentTypeId is required.As of now am getting it from existing replies that have added directly from share point site when a discussion is created.

But when i start to post a first message through sharepoint REST API,it fails because ContentTypeId is undefined.

Is there any way to find  ContentTypeId for replies?

Answer (score 0):

In your discussion list, click the "Message" content type. You would see the ContentTypeId in the url:

[image]

[image]